# Why add one to denominator when calculating discrete signal average power?

Tags: signal-processing

In order to calculate the average power of a continuous signal we use the following formula:

[image: Continuous Signal Average Power]

Which makes logical sense to me. However, when we're calculating it for a discrete signal, then we use the following formula:

[image: Discrete Signal Average Power]

My question, and confusion, is why we add one to the divisor of the summing co-efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of integers in interval $[n_0, n_1]$ is equal to $n_1-n_0+1$.

Example. Let's count the number of integers from $n_0=3$ to $n_1=7$:
$$3\le n\le7\qquad  \{3,4,5,6,7\}\qquad\text{5 integers total}$$
$$n_1-n_0+1=7-3+1=5$$

Comment: Yep... I need to go back to sleep... Cheers